# How do I run a program in QT creator?

Tags: qt, qml

Installed the QT creator program
Now, first of all, I'm just trying to run the first code through QML:
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Tile {
        width: root.width / 4
        height: root.height / 4
    }
}
```

Tile.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: "lightgreen"
    radius: 10
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 1
    Text {
        id: _firstText
        anchors.centerIn: root
        text: "1"
        font {
            pointSize: Math.min(root.width, root.height) / 3
            bold: true
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
**Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick**
```

And the second code through the console application:
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello wolrd" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following error:

**

```
13:23:56: Starting /home/IK@rt.ru/Рабочий стол/Hello/git/Cpp/Test2/build-Test-Desktop-Debug/Test ...
13:23:56: An unknown error in the process occurred.
13:23:56: Cannot start the terminal emulator "xterm", change the setting in the Environment options.
13:23:56: /home/IK@rt.ru/Рабочий стол/Hello/git/Cpp/Test2/build-Test-Desktop-Debug/Test exited with code -1
```

**
What to do? everything was running great on windows

Comment: Do you have the QtQuick library installed?

Comment: did you add `QT += qml quick` in `.pro`?

Comment: I think your problem relates to your installation and kits. please watch [Install Qt Open Source on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEXOkBm_fuo)

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, you probably didn't add `QT += quick qml` in your `.pro` or you have some mistakes in `main.cpp`, If you do all of this then your problem relates to your installation.

**This is my Test:**

1.**`.pro`**

```
QT += quick qml

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

2.**in `main.qml` :**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Tile {
        width: root.width / 4
        height: root.height / 4
    }
}
```

3.**in `Tile.qml`**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: "lightgreen"
    radius: 10
    border.color: "black"
    border.width: 1
    Text {
        id: _firstText
        anchors.centerIn: root
        text: "1"
        font {
            pointSize: Math.min(root.width, root.height) / 3
            bold: true
        }
    }
}
```

4.`in main.cpp`

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**This is the output**

[image]